# What happens to the current firebase analytics data when I replace the default firebase hosting domain with a new one?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-hosting

I have a firebase app with analytics and the default hosting (i.e. myproject.firebaseapp.com).
Now I want to use my own domain (i.e. myproject.com) for this firebase app.

My question is, do I need to change anything in analytics setup?
Would it keep the previous data and add the new ones?
Or I would lose the historical data altogether?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analytics data is tied to an app in the project, and not to a specific domain name. When adding a custom domain name, all you're essentially doing is adding an alias for the existing app(s). So all data will (or at least should) be maintained.

Comment: Thank you for your response Frank.

I'd like to add:
If your custom domain already have some historical data which you prefer to maintain, you can follow this migration guide to transfer the data from Google Analytics into Firebase Analytics:
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9447593?hl=en

I hope it helps someone.